# Boundary condition of gauge field for finite Euclidean action

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, topology, yang-mills, instantons

I am reading the book "Gauge theory of elementary particle physics" by Cheng & Li chapter 16 and I am confused by some statements.

In Euclidean 4D spacetime we have a $SU(2)$ gauge teory
\begin{equation}
S_E=\int dx^4 tr(F_{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu}),~~~F_{\mu \nu}=\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}+[A_{\mu},A_{\nu}]
\end{equation}
If we require $S_E$ to be finite, then we must have $F_{\mu \nu} \rightarrow 0$ for $r \rightarrow +\infty$, $r=\sqrt{x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$. This will give boundary condition for $A_{\mu}$

Now it is said the condition $A_{\mu} \rightarrow 0$ is too restrictive, instead, we can set $A_{\mu}\rightarrow U^{-1}\partial_{\mu}U$.

Here is my question: Since the theory is gauge-invariant, we can pick another gauge field $A'_{\mu}=g^{-1}A_{\mu}g+g^{-1}\partial_{\mu}g$ for some $g \in SU(2)$. If $g=U^{-1}$, we have
\begin{equation}
A'_{\mu} \rightarrow g^{-1}U^{-1}\partial_{\mu}Ug+g^{-1}\partial_{\mu}g=\partial_{\mu}UU^{-1}+U\partial_{\mu}U^{-1}=0, r\rightarrow +\infty
\end{equation}

This means we get the condition $A_{\mu} \rightarrow 0$ back (relabeling the gauge field)? So why do we emphasise the condition "$A_{\mu} \rightarrow U^{-1}\partial_{\mu}U$"?

Answer (score 1):

Any gauge transformation $g: B^4\to SU(2)$ is by definition continuous, in particular for $r=0$. The radial coordinate $r$ can be seen as a [homotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy) parameter. Since the restricted map $g|_{r}:S^3\to SU(2)$ for small enough $r$ has winding number $0$, it must also have it on the boundary $\partial B^4\cong S^3\cong\{r\!=\!\infty\}$ of spacetime. Hence we cannot unwind non-trivial instanton sectors by gauge transformations.

References:

1. S. Coleman, *Aspects of symmetry,* subsection 7.3.2.

Comment: Thanks. So since $g$ is a gauge transformation, it must be continuous. What about $U$ here? If $U$ is continuous, by the same reason, $U$ must be constant at $r=0$ and hence has winding number $0$ on any sphere? Further, if we set $U$ to be continuous everywhere except at $r=0$, then we can get non-trivial winding number?

Comment: $U$ is in Cheng & Li only defined at (or near) the boundary $r=\infty$.

Comment: Coleman's book says $A_{\mu}$ has the form $U^{-1}\partial_{\mu} U+O(1/r^2)$ for large $r$ and $U$ is independent of $r$, but if we go to the boundary, i.e., $r=\infty$, we have $A_{\mu}=0$. Is it a contradiction?